# Need an SQL query to calculate the sum of user activity time in desired period

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm looking for a way to find out how much time in total has each user been active during, for example, the month of February 2020. Is there a way this can be done by querying the MySQL database?

I have a **"user_activity"** table in my databese, which contains all changes that the user is making to his account.

It has 4 columns that can be important for this calculation:

1. **"field"** - this column gathers data on what type of change the user is making to his account, the value of this column is "active" for all cases where the user is activating/deactivating his account
2. **"old_value"** - this is the value of what is inside of "field" that was present before the change
3. **"new_value** - this is the new value of what is inside of "field"
4. **"activity_time"** - this is the time of the change

EXAMPLE TABLE: user_activity

```
| user_activity_id | user_id | field  | old_value | new_value | activity_time       |
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|        1         |    1    | active |     1     |     0     | 2020-01-01 15:45:00 |
|        2         |    1    | active |     0     |     1     | 2020-01-02 10:31:00 |
|        3         |    3    | active |     0     |     1     | 2020-01-02 16:22:00 |
|        4         |    4    | active |     0     |     1     | 2020-01-03 03:25:00 |
|        5         |    4    | active |     1     |     0     | 2020-01-06 19:59:00 |
```

So each time the user activates his account a line is entered in "user_activity" table with new activity_time and values *where field = "active" and old_value = 0 and new_value = 1*.

A single user can activate or deactivate his account multiple times during 1 month and I'm working on a table with tens of thousands of entries like this.

EXAMPLE DESIRED OUTPUT:

```
| user_id | active_hours_feb_2020 |
-----------------------------------
|    1    |          500          |
|    2    |           0           |
|    3    |          700          |
|    4    |          250          |
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the past activity time and calculate the difference. Think the query will work if you track the activity all the time.

query using lag - https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=9f6fea01dd9fdc3e91d1e446ec027927